# How can I hover over a Plotly tooltip to see more tooltips?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I made a python `plotly` chart where the `hover_data` is itself some html string that uses the title attribute to allow for more information on hover.

Illustratively:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px 

pd.DataFrame({
    'x':'This', 'y':[1], 'hover_info': ['<span title="This is some important detail">Value is One</span>']
}).pipe(px.bar, x='x', y='y', hover_data='hover_info')
```

[image]

Conceptually this is what I'm expecting:
[image]

And I kind of think it will work if I can manage to hover over the tooltip. However, plotly's tooltips disappear when I move my cursor to hover over them.

Any ideas?

I could not find a way to make tooltips persistent.